# What has changed that make companies, banks, utilities asking for the last four digits of my SS number, particularly when I am not new to them?

Tags: authentication

Why are companies, banks, utilities, etc. requesting the last four digits of my SS number, particularly when I have a long history with the entity and they are linked to my landline. Allowing their administrative staff to have access to my personal information is troubling.

Comment: you haven't seen any news about hacking in the last few years?

Answer (score 1):

It's just another factor of proving who you are. think of it as defense in depth and multi-factor authentication, something you have and something you know. They have you call from a verified number (something you have, but could possibly be spoofed) and they add a layer by asking something you know, the last 4 of your social.